# Google datastore left join equivalent

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Basically I am wondering if I might need to use a rdbms instead of google datastore

So, I have the following 3 kinds in gds

```
request_ledger
key | type   | content | sentTimestamp  
xyx   email    <ssd>     10-10-10 




request_recipient
key request_ledger                  to
1    key(request_ledger,xyz)    joe@bla.com
2    key(request_ledger,xyz)    john@bla.com



result_ledger 
key | request_ledger            | to          | deliveredTimestamp | bouncedTimestamp 
1     key(request_ledger,xyz)    joe@bla.com    10-10-11;
```

I am using separate kinds as much as possible so that I don't run into update/overwrite issues - I'm always just saving new entities instead of doing any updates.

The request_ledger and request_recipient entities are created at the same time,   However the result_ledger entities are created later as the result of a webhook, so basically the model above would translate into the following report:

- email to joe@bla was delivered at 10-10-11
- email to john@bla.com is still pending (i.e. no delivered or bounced webhook event received yet)

If this was a regular rdbms I could use left joins to allow me to report across the 3 tables and allows nulls where there is no correlating matches in result_ledger

e.g. something like..

```
select a.type, a.content, a.sentTimestamp, b.to, c.deliveredTimestamp, c.bouncedTimestamp from request_ledger a left join request_recipient b on a.key=b.request_ledger left join result_ledger on b.request_ledger = c.request_ledger and b.to = c.to
```

which would give me something like

```
a.type | a.content |a.sentTimestamp |b.to .      |c.deliveredTimestamp | c.bouncedTimestamp
email  <content>  10:10:10          joe@bla.com   10-10-11
email  <content>  10:10:10          john@bla.com
```

but in Google Datastore I am not sure if this would be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to forget about joins and normalized data structures when using Datastore. You may want to consider using an Entity Group; request_ledger as the parent and the result_ledger as the child.

You should consider moving/copying some data from your request_recipient to the request_ledger, but keep the request_recipient KEY in the object - this is helpful in the event you need to retrieve the entire request_recipient object.